# Activity name could not be resolved after creating an activity in eclipse

Tags: android

I have just added an activity to my project *(from the options)* in eclipse called **Dlg** as a result a `Dlg.java` file was created along with a `activity_dlg.xml`. Also added the activity in the `AndroidManifest.xml` however eclipse has placed a small cross next to the `Dlg.java` file and `activity_dlg` has been underlined  in

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_dlg);
```

and it states `activity_dlg` cannot be resolved or is not a field. Why is this happening all of a sudden. I Added activites a while ago and they were fine.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Do a Project -> Clean...

Comment: That worked. Could you post it as an answer so that I could mark it

Comment: You have some issue in layout file, please check it once.

Comment: @MistyD Answer added as requested

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "cannot be resolved or is not a field" error on the `R` class indicates that the changes you made (addition of the layout xml) is not reflected in the generated file. You can clean the project using menu Project -> Clean... to force re-generation of the `R` class.

Answer (score 0):

It probably means that for whatever reason the R.java file, which is automatically generated, isn't generated or incomplete.

This usually means you have an error in your xml file.

Assuming that activity_dlg.xml actually exists, you probably have an error in there. 
Maybe its referencing to an image or string which doesn't exists?

Open it up and check it carefully, not always does the xml reader underline errors.

If you can't find anything you can always try to clean your projects or restart eclipse, but that probably won't help.

Answer (score 0):

I think the newly added activity_dlg.xml is not associated with an id in R.java file.
Confirm this by going to R.java. Under this you have something like:

```
 public static final class layout {
        public static final int activity_dlg=0x7f030000;//This is some id to your layout
    }
```

If this is not present then u can right click on the project directory from eclipse and refresh. or Project->Clean to regenerate the R.java file.